# Unable to load sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I've started getting a rather cryptic error in one of my tests. Surefire report is as follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: de.systel.streckenmatching.GeoCoordinateTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.129 sec <<< FAILURE!
de.systel.streckenmatching.GeoCoordinateTest  Time elapsed: 0.128 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleDataMetaInfo: Unable to load sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:584)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.loadProvider(ServiceLoader.java:856)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ModuleServicesLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1078)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1301)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1386)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.<init>(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:346)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:604)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.forType(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:176)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.findAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:279)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.getAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:250)
    at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:180)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.getZero(Formatter.java:2437)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.<init>(Formatter.java:1956)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.<init>(Formatter.java:1978)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:3302)
    at org.junit.runner.Description.formatDisplayName(Description.java:114)
    at org.junit.runner.Description.createTestDescription(Description.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.describeChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:96)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.describeChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:352)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:359)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 'platform' attempted duplicate class definition for sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo. (sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo is in module jdk.localedata of loader 'platform')
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1109)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:183)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:780)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:701)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:505)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.loadProvider(ServiceLoader.java:854)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 'platform' attempted duplicate class definition for sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo. (sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo is in module jdk.localedata of loader 'platform')
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1109)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:183)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:780)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:701)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:505)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.loadProvider(ServiceLoader.java:854)
    ... 40 more
```

The test itself is absolutely nothing special, just validating `equals` for some POJO classes:

```
public class GeoCoordinateTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        
        
        GeoCoordinate coord1 = new GeoCoordinate();
        coord1.setLatitude(5.0);
        coord1.setLongitude(10.0);

        GeoCoordinate coord2 = new GeoCoordinate();
        coord2.setLatitude(5.0);
        coord2.setLongitude(10.0);
        
        GeoCoordinate coord3 = new GeoCoordinate();
        coord3.setLatitude(5.1);
        coord3.setLongitude(10.0);
        
        
        assertEquals(coord1, coord2);
        assertNotEquals(coord1, coord3);
    }

}
```

It happens under OpenJDK 14:

```
...>java -version
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I am puzzled. What is happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: The stack trace format `module/class...` (like `java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader`) suggests maven is being run on JDK 9+. Please check your JAVA_HOME variable. Or test `mvn -v` to see which JDK it's using.

Comment: @ernest_k Was in fact a wrong JDK (OpenJDK 14).

Answer (score 4):

I had this happen when I was upgrading from Java 8 to Java 11 while running the test with JetBrains' IDE Intellij IDEA.

What was happening in my case was that the Project SDK was different from the one being used by the `'platform'`.

In my case, the platform was Gradle's JVM. If anyone comes across this, know that you can set up the `Build Tool` to match the Project SDK by going to `Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build Tools`. Here you have options for `Gradle` or the question's `Maven`, among others.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me when I was upgrading from JDK11 to JDF15. This problem appears at JDK14+, but is fine at JDK13.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurred to me in an automated test project with JDK 15, TestNG, mongo-java-driver, Selenium, and other dependencies.

I had to upgrade to JDK 15 due to a bug in the mongo-driver with JDK 13. After this update, the error "**Unable to load sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo**" started to occur.

I solved it with the maven settings that I put below.

```
<properties>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.6</jacoco.version>
</properties>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>

    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Excellent. I would be cool if you could add some narrative describing how the solution solves the problem.

Comment: This problem occurred to me in an automated test project with JDK 15, TestNG, mongo-java-driver, Selenium, and other dependencies. I had to upgrade to JDK 15 due to a bug in the mongo-driver with JDK 13. 

After this update, the error "Unable to load sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo" started to occur.

I solved it with the maven settings that I put above.

Comment: Cool. Sorry I meant update your answer text

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly the same issue with **Java 8, Eclipse 2021-03** (refreshly installed).
Apparently Eclipse comes with its own JRE, and Gradle will use it as default.
To fix the issue, you need to go to **Preferences > Gradle** and manually **change Java Home to match your default/system/project Java Home**.